# Programmatically file one folder under another folder in FileNet P8

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I have a folder called 'Top' and 2 sub folders 'A' and 'B' underneath that. Now, I'm trying to move folder 'B' under folder 'A'. For this, I tried a create a RCR as follows..

*RCR = FolderA.File((IFolder)FolderB, AutoUniqueName.AUTO_UNIQUE, ((IFolder)FolderB).Name, DefineSecurityParentage.DO_NOT_DEFINE_SECURITY_PARENTAGE);*

Though this code executes without any error, I don't see Folder B moving under Folder A. Wondering is this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

I found that we have to just set the parent property and no need of RCR